# Can producers have the same clientId and publish to a topic in Artemis?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple producers using the same clientId to send messages to a durable topic. And on the consuming side, what would happen if the clientID is the same as the producer side but the subscription name is different?

E.g. The producer has a clientId of `123abc` and sends messages to a durable topic. A consumer is subscribed to this durable topic and this consumer has a clientId of `123abc` but also a subscriptionName of `abc123`? Would the consumer still be able to pick up the message? What would happened if I bring another consumer in the mix?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who may have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to what is lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Section 6.1.2 of the JMS 2 specification states:

> By definition, the client state identified by a client identifier can be ‘in use’ by only one client at a time.

By "client" the specification really means "connection." Therefore, the same client identifier can only be in use by one *connection* at a time. So if you create multiple producers from the same connection that's OK. However, creating multiple connections with the same client ID will fail before you even get to the point where you can create a producer as the broker will validate the client ID when the connection is created.

That said, there's no real point in setting the client ID on a connection that's just used for producing messages. Section 6.1.2 of the JMS 2 specification also states:

> The only use of a client identifier defined by JMS is its mandatory use in identifying an unshared durable subscription or its optional use in identifying a shared durable or non-durable subscription.

Therefore, it's not really necessary to set the client ID unless you're creating an unshared durable subscription or possibly a shared durable or non-durable subscription.

Comment: So when we create multiple connections from a factory (and each connection having a clientId of `123abc`), the fact that the `.createConnection()` supports concurent use, does that mean each connection will essentially wait since only one connection be active? (I've read that somewhere).

Comment: As soon as you try to create a connection with a duplicate client ID value an exception will be thrown. There will be no waiting.

Answer (score -1):

Two subscribers cannot have the same clientid: when they both try to connect to the broker, the second will go into exception. However, you can override the clientid: using TomEE or Tomcat you can add a simple line to `system.properties` file like this:

```
<classname>.activation.clientId=<newclientid>
```

No problem for producers.

Comment: Does the TomEE/Tomcat client ID override apply to ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm workinig with the old version of Artemis: ActiveMQ, but I think is the same.

Comment: What do you mean you're working with "the old version of Artemis: ActiveMQ"? Are you saying that you're working with ActiveMQ 5.x? If so, the two brokers are completely different and I wouldn't expect the configuration of one to work for the other.

Comment: I think it is the same, because [it is a standard API of JMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#setClientID-java.lang.String-)

Comment: And ... it is not a server or broker configuration, is a client configuration ...

Comment: `javax.jms.Connection#setClientID` *is*, of course, part of the JMS API, but your answer described a way to set it via system properties. Is that part of the JMS specification? Also, every JMS broker I'm aware of ships their own client implementation so that users can actually connect to the broker. Therefore, configuration specifics for one don't necessarily apply to the other.